# How to add payment gateway to register page of website

Tags: php, html, payment-gateway

I have a new project. Please note this is my first project. I am creating a PHP driving site and I need to create a payment gateway at the register page. How do i do this? - I really need a nail on the head direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, welcome to SO - your question is too wide and such questions generally don't receive a good feedback - if you want to get the best of this site try to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Payment gateways generally come with good documentations and set of APIs and are quite easy to be integrated.
The only thing you need to do is to choose one and then go to its developers guide and find one that matches your platform's language.

Among the payment gateways out there I find [Stripe](https://stripe.com) & [PayPal](https://paypal.com) more sophisticated! (specially the first one). They both have great documentations in PHP.

For example for Stripe it's enough to add this code to your `composer.json`,

```
{
  "require": {
    "stripe/stripe-php": "@stable"
  }
}
```

find the complete tutorial [here](https://github.com/stripe/wilde-things) and for more info you can have a look at [this Url](https://stripe.com/docs/examples) - for PayPal you can have a look at [this one](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki).